# Delete from Unidirectional Many-To-Many replationship, where Cascade.Remove is not an option

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities, to simplify, said Department and Employee, 
Department and Employee has a Unidirectional Many-to-Many relationship,
where Department has `employees` property but Employee cannot navigate to the departments.

Then to delete an Employee, I invoke`deleteById(employeeId)` or `delete(employee)` from EmployeeRepository
(Which extends a CrudRepository from Spring Data JPA)

This invocation will throw **JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException**, because it does not first remove the association in the **Department_Employee** join table. **The removal to the Employee must follow the removal to all his associations with his departments.**

What is a good way to achieve this?

I came up with one idea:

Use `@Modifying` with `@Query` to override the `delete` method from CrudRepository.

But Spring Data JPA seems does not support to run multiple queries sequentially in `@Query` annotation, I don't know how to first remove all associations then remove the employee in one JPQL query.

Please share your ideas or practices, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With problem like this I find it helpful to think in terms of Domain Driven Design, which is the basis of Spring Data repositories.

With DDD `Department` and `Employee` would be different aggregates and therefore have two separate repositories.
If you want to delete both, all the references to an employee and the employee itself this affects both repositories and therefore should be handled in two separate methods which then get called from a single service.

I also would tend to not use JPA here since deleting all the references is single SQL statement while it would require loading potentially many `Department` instances just to remove a reference and persisting them again.